# vue.js reactivity how dependency class might have many watcher subscribers

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-reactivity

As you know, for each data property, there's a `new Dep` class created. `Each Dep` class has subscribers of `watchers`.

I looked through vue.js source code and for each component, there's only ONE `watcher` class being created which also holds the `render` function(template of the component).

1) Could you describe the situation when and why `data` property of one of the components might have the `Dep` class which has more than one `watcher` class?

2) So can I sum up something like this: if we have a component which has 5 `data` properties. each of these 5 data properties has different `Dep` class instance. and each of those `Dep` class has the same `Watcher` and that `watcher` holds the component's `render` function. If state changes, one of those 5 `Dep` class's notify gets run and that notify runs its `watcher's` `render` function?

Comment: Hi Giorgi Lagidze. could you explain more your use case with sample data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this introduction useful:

https://medium.com/dailyjs/tracing-or-debugging-vue-js-reactivity-the-computed-tree-9da0ba1df5f9

As you've mentioned, each data property will have its own instance of `Dep`. Each `Dep` has a `subs` property that holds an array of subscribers. The subscribers in that array will all be instances of the `Watcher` class. If a data property changes then the corresponding `Dep` will notify each `Watcher` in its `subs`.

Each `Watcher` also holds references back to its dependencies, in a property called `deps`. This is just an array of the `Dep` objects to which the `Watcher` is subscribed.

You'll be able to see this in your browser developer tools. If you log a Vue instance you'll find a property called `_watchers` that holds all the watchers related to that component. Expanding their `deps` will lead you to the `Dep` objects, though it can be tricky to tell exactly which data property each `Dep` represents.

The rendering process has a `Watcher` that it uses to track its data dependencies.  You'll only get one of those per component instance.

A `Watcher` is also created if you use [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) or [$watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch). Again you'll be able to see these in `_watchers`.

Computed properties have one `Watcher` each. Those will be present in the `_watchers` array but it's easier to see them in `_computedWatchers`.

A key thing to note is that dependencies are flattened. If you use a computed property you'll actually just get a dependency on all the data properties that contributed to it. You can't form a direct dependency on the computed property itself.

So to go back to your original question:

1. Rendering, computed properties and `watch` will all contribute to the `subs` of a `Dep`. Computed properties will often contribute more subscribers than you might expect due to the flattening of the dependencies.
2. Almost. The `render` function isn't called directly. When the `Watcher` for rendering is notified of a data change it will actually just add the component to a queue. That rendering queue won't be processed until the start of the next tick.

Comment: Hey skirtle, It's been a long time since you answered this question. I have one more question, if you don't mind. If data property changes which also changes computed property, we will have 2 watcher class that have to run. 1) component watcher render 2) computed watcher.. These 2 are the subscribers of the data property that we changed, so these 2 watcher get added to queue. My question is, watcher rendering class should always be the last in the queue, since we might be using computed in template, so first, we have to run computed watchers and then rendering watcher at last. right ?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili The watchers for computed properties don't need to go through the queue. They just invalidate the cached value immediately. The new value for the computed property won't be calculated until something tries to access it.

Comment: so, in the queue, only rendering watchers end up ?

Comment: so if I have a data property that has 2 watchers (rendering watcher, computed watcher) and I change this data property in some function, what will happen is vue will run all the watchers except rendering watcher . After running them, all the values will be changed. and then, as the last step, rendering watcher will be added to queue, correct ?